# Python requests error - SSL UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED

Tags: python, ssl, https, openssl, urllib3

I am running Python 3.10 in Ubuntu 22.04 and I am getting an error when I try to access a https server using requests.get.

Things I have varied, with no luck

- [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) versions: 3.0.0 and 1.1.1l
- Different Python `requests` package versions
- Different Python `cryptography` package versions
- Different Python `urllib3` package versions

The most striking thing is that the Python code **works perfectly well** if I access all other https servers I tested, apart from `"https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/"`. For example, `requests.get("https://github.com")` returns a 200 status code.

Do you have any idea of what could be happening here? Could it be due to a black-listed IP?

**Python call**

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/")
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1040, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 414, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 512, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1070, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1341, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:997)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nomads.ncep.noaa.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:997)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 563, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nomads.ncep.noaa.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:997)')))
```